# How to clone select and set selected option and pass it back as string. (doing as part of custom formatter of jqgrid)

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using a custom formatter for a column in jqgrid.

Code :

```
function getCellContentForFormula(cellValue, opts, rowObject) { 
var splitResult = "FHLMC 30 YR";
var selectId = opts.colModel.name + ':' + rowObject.coupon+ ':' + 'substituteSelect';
    //      var $selectBnchmark = $('#productSelect').clone().attr("id",selectId).val(splitResult);
var $selectBnchmark = $('#productSelect').clone().attr("id", selectId);
$('#'+selectId+ ' option[value='+splitResult+']').attr('selected', 'selected');
var bnchMarkSelect = $('<span>').append($selectBnchmark).remove().html();
console.log(bnchMarkSelect);
return '<br/>'+ bnchMarkSelect;
    }
```

The above code is correctly creating the drop down with the options but is not showing the selected value.

Console.log output:

```
 <select id="valueOfCMPlusTwo:5:substituteSelect" class="prodSelect"> <option  value="">-Select-</option><option value="FHLMC 15 YR">FHLMC 15 YR</option><option value="FHLMC 30 YR">FHLMC 30 YR</option></select>
```

I am having trouble combining lines 3 and 4, I need the output like :

```
<select id="valueOfCMPlusTwo:5:substituteSelect" class="prodSelect"> <option value="">-Select-</option><option value="FHLMC 15 YR">FHLMC 15 YR</option><option value="FHLMC 30 YR" selected="selected">FHLMC 30 YR</option></select>
```

Please help.

Comment: Later I need to use customEdit of jqgrid, but for now I just want to show the html elements in the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It you work with the custom formatter you should just work with strings and not use and `jQuery` operation. For example if you have HTML fragment represented `<select>` having "blabla" as the "id" and you want to set new `id` you can just use string [replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) method. In the same way you can rewrite your custom formatter.

You current code is much much slowly. You should understand, that every `$("#myid")` operation is the slower the more elements with id you have on you page. Moreover you use [jQuery.clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) which has not fixed bugs. So I strictly recommend you simplify the code of your custom formatter and use only string or `RegExp` operations inside.

Comment: Thank you. I rewrote as you suggested. The code is huge to post here. What I did was, instead of clone I used the .html()  to get the html of the selects. Then did string manipulation to set the new id and selected value.

Comment: @silpa: I am glad to hear, that the problem is solved. I hope that you use `$('#productSelect').html()` **not inside of the custom formatter function**. The custom formatter will be called in all the cells of the column and it will make the code slowly. If you need the current contain of `$('#productSelect').html()` you can define for example `$('#productSelect').change` event handler and save the html code (`$('#productSelect').html()`) in a variable which you use inside of the custom formatter. Probably you have already implemented all in the way or another close way. Good luck!